# Correct use of ForAll in PLINQ

Tags: vb.net, entity-framework, plinq

I have a code which iterate through a list retrieved by a LINQ and created a new object list with some added properties. I want to improve performance by using PLINQ and ForAll(). 
I tried the following;

```
Dim RetrieveList_Qry = From Prod In DB.Products.AsParallel().AsOrdered()
                                   Where Prod.ProductParentID > 0

If Me.AuthorityList Is Nothing Then
  Dim AuthorityGroup_Qry = From AG In DB.AuthorityGroups
  AuthorityList = AuthorityGroup_Qry.ToList
End If

Dim product As Product
ProdList = New ObjectModel.ObservableCollection(Of Product)

RetrieveList_Qry.ForAll(Sub(item)

product = New Product(item.ProductID,
                      item.ProductType,
                      item.ProductLabel )

*For Each PA As In item.ProductAuthorities*
   Dim AG As Data.AuthorityGroup = (From AuthorityGroup In Me. AuthorityList Where   
   PA.AuthorityGroupID = AuthorityGroup.AuthorityGroupID).FirstOrDefault
   product.AddProductAuthority(PA.ProductID,
   PA.AuthorityGroupID,
   PA.IsActive,
   AG.AuthorityGroupName)
Next
SyncLock (ProdList)
 ProdList.Add(product)
End SyncLock

End Sub)
```

But this doesn't seem to work. Some times it gives results but sometimes gives following exception at the italic line in above code:
"Unable to set field/property ProductAuthorities on entity type System.Data.Entity.DynamicProxies.AuthorityGroup_79066B4E83621583B6152BDC."

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: first of all... ForAll may run by multiple threads and ProdList is not thread safe.

Comment: Yes. getting this to run on multiple threads is what I want. I changed my code to lock the ProdList.

Comment: First, adding locking eliminates any parallelism benefit. Second, trying to load/modify db data "in parallel" won't work. Sending 100 update statements is always slower than executing a single statement that updates 100 records. PLINQ won't fix bad data access code. What are you trying to do?

Comment: This is not updating db data. I am retrieving data and create a different data object which in turn be used to create a Hierarchical structure to populate a tree